# given two queues, find which elements of the first are not in the second.

Tags: data-structures

I tried puting all elements in two arrays and then comparing them using two loops. But I am asked to not use other data structures, only queues.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your current code so we can help.

Comment: I’m a beginner :(

Comment: Happy to help beginners, but reading [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) should help you understand what the community expects so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, not particularly efficient, is to compare each item in one queue against every item in the other queue. If you can't access the queue as an array, then you just dequeue an item, compare it, and then enqueue it. Imagine you have these two queues:

```
q1 = [5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 6]
q2 = [4, 2, 1, 10, 12, 3]
```

So you remove the first item from q1:

```
x = q1.dequeue();
```

`x` is now equal to `5`, and `q1` now looks like this:

```
q1 = [7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 6]
```

Now, for each item in `q2`, you remove it from the queue, compare it against `x`, and then re-queue it. Something like:

```
y = q2.dequeue();
if (x == y) { print "matching item " + x; }
q2.enqueue(y);
```

You do that for every item in `q2`.

Then, add `x` back to `q1`, resulting in:

```
q1 = [7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 6, 5]
```

Then, repeat the process. Dequeue the from `q1`, test it against every item in `q2`. Do that until you've checked all of the items in `q1`.

It's the same algorithm you'd use with two arrays, but rather than indexing directly into the array, you just use the queue to move items to the front.

I'll leave the coding to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful :).

Comment: @AmelBr If this helped you out, please consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.